# Three.js three.interaction three.transformControls

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a problem with my project.
I use three.interaction to get click event on some objects and add to them the transformControls.

the problem is that: the transform controls blocks the click event in the other objects, i think because it blocks the raycast.

some solutions?

```
var camera, scene, renderer;
var geometry, material, mesh;

var transformControls;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10 );
    camera.position.z = 1;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 0.2, 0.2, 0.2 );
    material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();





    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    const interaction = new THREE.Interaction(renderer, scene, camera);

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( mesh );

    mesh.on('click', function (ev) {
        click(ev);
    });

     mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( mesh1 );
    mesh1.position.set(0.3, 0, 0);

    mesh1.on('click', function (ev) {
        click(ev);
    });



}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}

function render() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}


function click(ev){

console.log("click");

    var transformControls = scene.getObjectByName("transformControls", true);
  var objControlled = scene.getObjectByName("objControlled", true);

  if (transformControls === undefined || transformControls === null) {
    transformControls = new THREE.TransformControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    transformControls.addEventListener('change', render);
    transformControls.name = "transformControls";

    scene.add(transformControls);

  }

  if (objControlled === undefined || objControlled === null) {

    try {
      transformControls.attach(ev.data.target);
      ev.data.target.name = "objControlled";
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }

  }
  else {

    try {
      transformControls.detach(objControlled);
      objControlled.name = "oldControlled";

      transformControls.attach(ev.data.target);
      ev.data.target.name = "objControlled";
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
}
```

js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h80g42wk/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `THREE.Interaction` extension to get the wanted behavior.

Result can be easily obtainable binding eventlisteners to the canvas and managing raycast yourself. I might say it's even easier than using said extension.

This way, you have control over which objects you want your raycast to check intersections against.

---

Add objects to a group instance, to limit objects you want to raycast against.

```
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

group = new THREE.Group();
group.add( mesh, mesh1 );
scene.add( group );
```

Simply bind a `mousedown` event to your canvas element and inside function callback you proceed to raycast against group and attach controls to object if it's not already attached to it.

```
// on initialization
renderer.domElement.addEventListener( 'mousedown', clickEvent );

// inside mousedown callback
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject( group, true );

if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
    let object = intersects[0].object;

    if ( control.object === undefined || control.object !== object ) {
        control.attach( object );
        render();
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/tawhurL0/)